How would I create multiple variables depending on the amount of items in a list?
I have a list with items which are pulled from a firebase database. I would like individual counters for each item but one variable isn't doing this for me and is adding 1 to each item on the list. Picture attached to show.
Code I have:
struct DrinksMenuView: View {
    @State var quantityItem: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        List (menumodel.list) { item in
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    VStack {
                        Text(item.id)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        Text("123 kcal, 330ml")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    HStack{
                        Button {
                            if quantityItem > 0 {
                                self.quantityItem -= 1
                            }
                            
                        }label: {
                            Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                                .tint(Color.black)
                        }
                        Text("\(quantityItem)")
                        Button {
                            self.quantityItem += 1
                        }label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                .tint(Color.black)
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        .padding(.all)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        
        
    }
}
#Preview {
    DrinksMenuView()
}


you need to use a dictionary to count items on each list
@State private var quantities: [String: Int] = [:]

Change your buttons as the following:
HStack {
    Button {
        decrementQuantity(for: item.id)
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
            .tint(Color.black)
    }
    Text("\(quantities[item.id, default: 0])")
    Button {
        incrementQuantity(for: item.id)
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            .tint(Color.black)
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
.padding(.all)

then use these:
private func incrementQuantity(for id: String) {
    quantities[id, default: 0] += 1
}

private func decrementQuantity(for id: String) {
    if let currentCount = quantities[id], currentCount > 0 {
        quantities[id]! -= 1
    }
}


You need to create a ListRow view that holds a variable for each item.
E.g:
struct ListRow: View {
    let item: Item
    
    @State private var quantityItem: Int = 0

    var body: some View {

        //...

    }
}

struct DrinksMenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List (menumodel.list) { item in
            ListRow(item: item)
        }
    }
}

Alternatively, as Hezy Ziv mentioned, if you need to use these variables outside the ListRow view you could use an array/dictionary that holds all variables.

No, the State would stay available even if you scroll it off screen
